# Trouble autoformatting numbers that are stored as strings

Tags: vba, excel

I built a routine that copies and pastes data and performs various analysis on said data once it is imported into my book.  The analysis portion works fine, but the data appears to be stored online in various excel books as strings when they are in fact ints and longs.  Excel recognizes this and annotates every cell with the little green tick mark and offers me to format them as numbers since they are stored as strings or I suppose "text."  It is massively slowing down the workbook as there are approximately 10 tabs with this information and they all have the same issue.

Another part of the problem is that there are legitimate strings in the data that are **NOT** numbers so formatting the entire sheet to be numbers will not work.

For example:  The sheets the data is imported from might have strings in rows 5,6 and all strings in column A and columns C to approximately J would have numbers formatted as strings or text. Then there might be a break for a few rows and the pattern would start all over again.

Thanks in advance!

Code below is merely for the accessing and copying the data as the rest of the analysis is conducted in a fairly large function:

```
Function GetOiData(productID As String, targetSheet As Worksheet, controlPanel As Worksheet)
'Function access OI data from the CME website and copies it into the book for all products
Dim filePath As String
Dim reportDate As String

reportDate = controlPanel.Cells(1, 5)
filePath = "http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductDetailsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=" & reportDate & "&reportType=P&productId=" & productID

Workbooks.Open Filename:=filePath
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy

targetSheet.Activate
With targetSheet
    .Cells(1, 1).Select
    .Paste
    .Cells(1, 1).Select
End With

'Clears clipboard and closes CSV file to avoid potential contamination
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Windows("voiProductDetailsViewExport").Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks("voiProductDetailsViewExport").Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Function
```

Comment: Try using `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` in place of the `.Paste` that way the text formatting doesn't carry from the source file. The cells should be General format then, which should prevent the little format warnings. I've never seen those cause workbook slow down though, so you may want to check if it's things like formulas that refer to large ranges of data or something like that. Formula issues (not specifically errors) are just a much more likely source in my experience.

Comment: I will take a look at this.  Thank you @JMichael !  I am pretty sure it's the warnings because only those sheets that contain that data populate very slowly, but I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sup>**First problem:** ... but the data appears to be stored online in various excel books as strings when they are in fact ints and longs.</sup>

Assuming that no leading or trailing spaces or non-breaking spaces exist, run this quick routine to cycle through the workbook and convert the text-that-look-like-numbers to true numbers.

```
Sub fixTextThatLookLikeNumbers()
    Dim w As Long, c As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For w = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
            With .Worksheets(w)
                For c = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
                    With .Columns(c)
                        If CBool(Application.CountA(.Cells)) Then _
                            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), _
                                    DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
                    End With
                Next c
            End With
        Next w
    End With
End Sub
```

That will work on columns formatted as General but not on columns specifically formatted as Text.

> <sup>**Second problem:** Another part of the problem is that there are legitimate strings in the data that are NOT numbers so formatting the entire sheet to be numbers will not work.</sup>

That code could be modified to force a General format on all columns if you have mix-and-match formatting currently going on.

Here is a quick rewrite of your function's code that should use direct transfer of raw values rather a copy and paste (or pastespecial) operation.

```
Function GetOiData(productID As String, targetSheet As Worksheet, controlPanel As Worksheet)
    'Function access OI data from the CME website and copies it into the book for all products
    Dim filePath As String, reportDate As String, data As Range

    reportDate = controlPanel.Cells(1, 5).Value
    filePath = "http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductDetailsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=" & reportDate & "&reportType=P&productId=" & productID

    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath, ReadOnly:=True)

        With .Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            targetSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value2
        End With

        'closes CSV file to avoid potential contamination
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    'this always turns back on when you exit the function
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped !  I am going to try Michael's simple solution up top and if that doesn't work effectively I'll give yours a go.  I'd rather stay simpler if possible.

Comment: No problem. I took a little time on your function and turned it into a direct value transfer. Without involving hte clipboard at all, it would seem to be another solution. Remember to keep an eye out for leading/trailing spaces added by the web site.

Comment: Thanks very much!  That's a big help I will make those changes and for some reason attempting to paste the special values seems to be breaking the macro for some reason.  Nothing copies over.  I am attempting to rerun it with the original code to make sure it's that change causing it.  I will implement your suggestions.  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately the function you wrote appears to be crashing.  Any idea why Jeeped?

Comment: Yeah, I don't like posting things that I cannot test. Can I get one of those XLS files from the public FTP site (ftp.cmegroup.com) or can you provide a valid URl that will down load one?

Comment: http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductDetailsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=20160212&reportType=P&productId=425

Comment: That link may not work anymore given that it's old.  if not i'll post a new one.

Comment: I changed teh function to a sub and used the hard-coded URL with success but the DL delivery was very slow. I was planning on having another look at it tomorrow to see if a urldownloadtofile might be better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103729/discussion-between-stormsedge-and-jeeped).

Comment: I found that UrlDownloadToFile is a vastly superior method of accessing the XLS. See [this sample workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/CME_DL_to_File.xlsb).